# Did bookies take bets in Pro-Wrestling before 'kayfabe' was common knowledge?

Tags: betting, pro-wrestling

I was curious whether bookies actually accepted bets in Professional Wrestling, given that it is now common knowledge that results are

> pre-scripted! :p

And it seems they do! Despite the worked nature, only very few people know of the results ahead of time, so one could see how bets could still be taken. It would just be more like betting on, say, the Oscars, than a boxing match. You just accept you're betting on who Vince McMahon picked rather than the result of a fair fight.

However, there was a time when that was not so well known - e.g. early 80s and before - and wrestling promotions like the WWF would take great efforts to protect this secret.

I'm curious whether bookies took bets back then? Did they avoid Pro-Wrestling (maybe it wasn't common knowledge in public but it was in the gambling industry)? And if they did take bets, how did they avoid the scrutiny of the authorities given the results were fixed?

Comment: Anecdote: in some countries in Europe, in the 60's and 70's, I remember that the fighters (and the winners!) of a reunion had to be declared at the local police station before it starts. So that the force knew in advance which fights would cause problems, and they could prevent brawls in the public because of what they thought was a fraud.

Comment: Whether bookies took bets I can's say. However, professional wrestling has been known to be scripted for several decades.

Comment: @GreenMatt Right? My peak watching of WWF was early 80’s and we knew.